# Android when launch app on a small screen some of the elements are outside the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have an issue with elements layout on the main activity. I tested my app on 1280x720 screen and all elements were situated right, but when I launched it on 480x320 screen, my ImageView fell outside the screen. How can I fix this in activity_main.xml layout? Here is the screenshot of my app element layout: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuLSG.jpg)
The code of activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fefefe"
    >

    <TextView android:text="Расчет длины реза натяжных потолков Apply         apply-potolki.ru"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:background="#41d219"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#f6fcf4"
        android:textColorLink="#336823"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <TextView android:text="Введите номер рисунка из каталога Apply, три цифры."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        android:textColor="#919090"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/catNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="Номер рисунка"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Найти"
        />

    <TextView android:text=" "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/anno"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        android:textColor="#919090"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <TextView android:text=" "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sizeText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        android:textColor="#919090"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/estL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Рассчитать"/>

    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/estLtext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9dada"
        android:textColor="#191970"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Wtext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9dada"
        android:textColor="#191970"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Ltext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9dada"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <TextView android:text="Для расчета стоимости умножьте длину реза на стоимость погонного метра. " android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        android:textColor="#919090"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Справка"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Выход"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/photo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen on smaller screens? If you want scrolling, you need to add an explicit `<ScrollView>` to your layout, most likely as the root element containing the `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Do you used the android material design library? https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html, it can help you to maintain different size of screen

Comment: I need the same look like on large screen.

Comment: you can use android:weightSum [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) to look similar in different screen resolution. But if you have more component scroll view is good.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about weightSum?